# How to convert Long type datetime to DateTime with correct time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

For example `1297380023295` should be 2010/2/11 9 AM
I use this code right now

```
        long dateNumber = num;
        long beginTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
        DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(beginTicks + dateNumber * 10000);

        return dateValue;
```

The result of this function is 1 AM,It is GMT.
What can I do with it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're looking for the `ToLocalTime()` method:

```
long unixDate = 1297380023295;
DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime date= start.AddMilliseconds(unixDate).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: I found the following link more useful
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6156193/3728916

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: That method takes .Net ticks, not Unix timestamps.

Comment: @SLaks +1 for correction thanks man you're right can you little guide me how i can get only date section using your code

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: You're looking for the `.Date` property.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes and i found it working using 
DateTime myDate = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(rd[0]));
string mydate2 =    myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: Unless you're actually using OLE, that's now what you want.

Answer (score 10):

```
long a= 634792557112051692;
//a= ticks time
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(a);
   Response.Write(dt.Hour.ToString());


//dt.hour convert time ticks to time hour
```

Answer (score 7):

U can use `static` methods from `DateTimeOffset`.

`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds()`

`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

Depends in wich format you have your ticks.

and if u want `DateTime` you can use for example

```
var ticks = 1635091250;
var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(ticks).DateTime;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the DateTimeKind when you create a new DateTime object, so you could specify that as UTC and then use .ToLocalTime to convert it to local time:

```
        long dateNumber = 1297380023295;
        long beginTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;

        DateTime dt = new DateTime(beginTicks + dateNumber * 10000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        MessageBox.Show(dt.ToLocalTime().ToString());
```

Comment: How can i convert like `DateTime.Parse("22:34")`  to `long`

Answer (score 1):

Powershell script piece, just FYI

```
$minDate = New-Object "System.DateTime"
$minDate = $minDate.AddYears(1969)
$minDate.AddMilliseconds(1446616420947)
```