# Convert DateTime to long and also the other way around

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to store dates as numbers in a table. I know how to do that but I don't know how to go back. How can I cast a long variable to ToDateTime.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
long t = now.ToFileTime();
DateTime today = t.ToDateTime;  // I am looking for something like this line. This Method does not exist
```

I know there are many ways of converting DateTime to long. I don't mind which technique to use. I just want to have a way where I can convert back and forth.

Comment: @DourHighArch: I disagree. The question is precisely stated and the intent is clear. "Got a `DateTime`, how to reversibly convert it to a `long`?" This question can be and deserves to be answered. I had precisely this question, and got the answer right here thanks to the OP. There is nothing more frustrating than answers saying "Why do you want to do that? DBs can store dates and times." And the question gets unanswered.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

To long from DateTime:

[`long DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

To DateTime from long:

[`new DateTime(long)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)

Comment: Maybe DateTime.Now.Ticks?

Comment: @Darth: it isn't a static property but instance.

Comment: @tgarcia in a millisecond* there are 10,000,000 ticks in a second

Comment: @Alexander, that's right, 10,000 ticks in a **millisecond**. Thanks! I'm gonna delete the mistaken comment to prevent any confusion.

Comment: Here is the conversion for ticks into useful time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Convert datetime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") to long?

Answer (score 15):

From long to DateTime: `new DateTime(long ticks)`

From DateTime to long: `DateTime.Ticks`

Answer (score 11):

use the pair [`long t = now.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) and [`DateTime Today = new DateTime(t)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `ToFileTime`, you'll want to use [FromFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx) to go the other way. But [note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx):

> Ordinarily, the FromFileTime method
>   restores a DateTime value that was
>   saved by the ToFileTime method.
>   However, the two values may differ
>   under the following conditions:
>
> If the serialization and deserialization of the DateTime value occur in different time zones. For
>   example, if a DateTime value with a
>   time of 12:30 P.M. in the U.S. Eastern
>   Time zone is serialized, and then
>   deserialized in the U.S. Pacific Time
>   zone, the original value of 12:30 P.M.
>   is adjusted to 9:30 A.M. to reflect
>   the difference between the two time
>   zones.
>
> If the DateTime value that is serialized represents an invalid time
>   in the local time zone. In this case,
>   the ToFileTime method adjusts the
>   restored DateTime value so that it
>   represents a valid time in the local
>   time zone.

If you don't care which `long` representation of a DateTime is stored, you can use `Ticks` as others have suggested (**Ticks is probably preferable**, depending on your requirements, since the value returned by `ToFileTime` seems to be in the context of the Windows filesystem API).

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities (note that the those long values aren't the same as the Unix epoch.

For your example (to reverse `ToFileTime()`) just use `DateTime.FromFileTime(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DateTime constructor that takes a long.

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(t); // where t represents long format of dateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   long dateTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
   Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
   Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(dateTime));
   Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use seconds since 1970 instead of Ticks:

UTC:

```
long secondsSince1970 = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Local time:

```
long secondsSince1970 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000000 - 62135596800;
```

And back to DateTime

```
DateTime value = DateTime.MinValue.AddSeconds(secondsSince1970).AddYears(1969);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add some additional conversion from string to DateTime to long

```
string timeString = "2016-08-04";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(timeString);
long dateTime = date.Ticks;
```

And here is the shorthand sort of speak:

```
long dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-04").Ticks;

//And for the long to DateTime

DateTime date = new DateTime(dateTime);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please review the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity Is that edit enough?

Comment: That certainly now covers off on the key points in the question. The two criticisms I have are that you've introduced parsing for no good reason - the OP didn't ask about parsing - and you've not really added any compelling new information than the existing answers offer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it was just some extra stuff that I am dealing right now and thought to share my additional experience. I will try to keep on point for future answers.

Comment: Then say why you've added it. Give it some context as to why you think this is a valuable addition.