# Why does Convert.ToDateTime(Int64) fail?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Why does the following fail w/ an "Invalid cast from 'Int64' to 'DateTime'." exception?

```
long oldDate=new DateTime(2015, 1, 1).Ticks;
DateTime newDate=Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);
```

.Ticks is a long/Int64 and the Convert.ToDateTime(Int64) MSDN docs show the method accepting a long/Int64.

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(
  long value
)
```

EDIT:
As pointed out by ebyrob below it should be:

```
long oldDate=new DateTime(2015, 1, 1).Ticks;
DateTime newDate=new DateTime(oldDate);
```

Comment: relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/4964660/85371

Comment: `new DateTime(oldDate);` would probably work here...  Convert logic probably isn't quite sure what you're trying to do.  `Convert` has to accept every type that supports conversion whether it works or not.

Comment: ebyrob identified the problem. It should be new DateTime() not Convert.ToDateTime().

Answer (score 7):

From the MSDN documentation on `Convert.ToDateTime Method (Int64)`:

> Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

And

> Return Value
>   Type: System.DateTime
>   This conversion is not supported. No value is returned.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/400f25sk.aspx (the link points to .NET 4.5 documentation but it's the same for all versions down to 2.0).

I'm not sure why this is not supported especially if `new DateTime(oldDate)` works well:

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(oldDate);
```

Comment: "Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException." => Ha!  Useful.  Must be one of those "we really shouldn't have done that" remnants from the v1.x era.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.FromBinary(oldDate)` does work