# how to C# convert ulong to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, ulong

In my C# program I'm receiving datetime from a PLC. It is sending data in "**ulong**" format.
How can I convert ulong to DateTime format?
for example I am receiving:

```
ulong timeN = 99844490909448899;//time in nanoseconds
```

then I need to convert it into DateTime ("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") format.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What time is 99844490909448899?

Comment: Is it a unix date? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964634/how-to-convert-long-type-datetime-to-datetime-with-correct-time-zone)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. no, it is Distributed Clock System Time (known as DC Time for short) in the form of a linear, 64-bit unsigned integer value. The time is expressed in nanoseconds.

Comment: @user2964067: *Duration* can be expressed in nanoseconds. Absolute time can not. What is your point of reference?

Comment: You have to add that to your question. If that value can be transformed to `100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.` you can use this [DateTime constructors that takes a long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As of [this page](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcplclib_tc2_ethercat/html/TcPlcLibTcEtherCAT_T_DCTIME.htm&id=) (german), the point of reference is `2000/01/01 00:00 UTC`.

Comment: Dear Gene, yes you are true. So how can I convert that in c# to DateTime?

Comment: DateTime does not have the resolution to support nanoseconds, you have to work with ticks (a tick is 100 nanoseconds).

Comment: @user2964067: Do `var d = new DateTime(timeN/100)`. (Because ticks is in 100 nanoseconds interval).

Comment: @PMF That gives the wrong date because DateTime(long) has a different reference date. The best way to solve it is probably to create a datetime for the reference date, then a timespan with timeN/100, then add the timespan to the reference datetime.

Comment: Dear PMF, DateTime has no constructor for ulong.

Comment: @user2964067: There is one for Int64 ("signed long"). Shouldn't matter. But I was really overlooking the fact that the reference time is different. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static DateTime GetDTCTime(ulong nanoseconds, ulong ticksPerNanosecond)
{
    DateTime pointOfReference = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    long ticks = (long)(nanoseconds / ticksPerNanosecond);
    return pointOfReference.AddTicks(ticks);
}

static DateTime GetDTCTime(ulong nanoseconds)
{
    return GetDTCTime(nanoseconds, 100);
}
```

This gives a date time of: `01 March 2003 14:34:50` using the following call:

```
ulong timeN = 99844490909448899;//time in nanoseconds
var theDate = GetDTCTime(timeN);
```

Comment: Since the point of reference is in UTC, it may be desirable to explicitly set the Kind to UTC (e.g., `pointOfReference = new DateTime(2000,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)`), particularly if conversions to and from local time are needed.

Comment: Thanks to David and drf