# long value to date c#

Tags: c#, datetime

My server is sending me the following value 13928550480000 which I know represents the date 02/19/2014. But I am not able to figure out how to get to the date from the long value.

I tried various ways of converting long to date using c# date time class but not able to get to the correct date i.e. 02/19/2014

```
        long dateL = 13928550480000;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(dateL);
        var dtstr = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        var onlyDate = dt.Date;

        DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime date = start.AddMilliseconds(dateL).ToLocalTime();
        var dtstr1 = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: "which I know represents the date 02/19/2014" How?  What is the conversion formula?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Long type datetime to DateTime with correct time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964634/how-to-convert-long-type-datetime-to-datetime-with-correct-time-zone)

Comment: Its a weblogic server. I have a way of verifying it but don't have access to the formula.

Comment: How do you verify it? Can you reuse the code?

Comment: @Tawnos He is using the answer code, and it's not working so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes i @Tawnos pointed out i am using the code in the other sample but its not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your source number represents *number of 0.10 ms increments since 1-1-1970* (either that or a typo):

```
    long dateL = 13928550480000;

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTime date = start.AddMilliseconds(dateL/10).ToLocalTime();
                                         //    ***
                                         //     ^------

    var dtstr1 = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");  // 02/19/2014
```

I suspect the time zone difference is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: try using 1392855048000.

Comment: You will get 5/18/2411 if you start with 13928550480000 (four zeros) and forget to divide by 10 in the place indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you write too many zeros at the end of your big number?  That is, does it really end in 0000 and not just 000?

If it really is 0000, then it appears to be measuring time in 100-microsecond increments (10,000 time increments per second).  But it is probably also giving you time in GMT and you are expecting to derive local time from it.  The time 1392855048 seconds from Jan. 1, 1970 would be 10 minutes 48 seconds past midnight on Feb. 20, 2014.  Depending on your time zone, that could be sometime on Feb. 19 local time.

Comment: I think the code in the answer by D Stanley is saying the same thing I just said.