# DateTime format from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#

I'm converting DateTime to a long result in Java, And the other side I need it the result on C#.

```
final long result = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 08, 25, 0, 0)).getTime();
```

The result is something like ***1598306400000***

What is the proper C# code?

Comment: Have you read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.millisecond?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Long type datetime to DateTime with correct time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964634/how-to-convert-long-type-datetime-to-datetime-with-correct-time-zone)